# understanding htmlOptions with Yii-bootstrap

Tags: php, css, yii, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Yii-bootstrap widgets for creating my website.

[Yii Framwork: bootstrap Extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/bootstrap/)

[Yii Bootstrap demo](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/)

I am trying to understand the `htmlOptions`, that can be used to override the default look and feel of the widgets. From what I read, I understood that the `htmloptions` cannot be randomly given, and should be given as array or hierarchical data depending upon the type of the widget, but when I try to implement the same it is not working properly.

For example, I am trying to customize the "heading font size" and "background color" for the "Hero-unit" containter. For that, I modified the "css" file to add one more style class called "hero-unit1" (the default style class is "hero-unit"). I kept the rest of the stuff as it is.

In the code, I implemented the widget as follows:

```
        <?php $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BootHero', array(
            'heading' => "Test Header !!",
            'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'hero-unit1'),
        )); ?>

           <p>Test content. Try it now.</p>
           <p><?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootButton', array(
                'type'=>'primary',
                'size'=>'large',
                'label'=>'Action',
            )); ?>
           </p>
        <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

However, when I see the corresponding "html code" that is generated for this, I see the following:

```
<div class="hero-unit1 hero-unit"><h1> Test Header !!</h1> 
   <p>Test content. Try it now.</p>
   <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Action</a></p>
</div>
```

The culprit, as I see is the **class="hero-unit1 hero-unit"** part, i.e. the class is not getting set properly. I thought that should have got overridden by giving htmlOptions but it is not happening. Any pointers would certainly help.....thanks !!

Comment: use developer tools in chrome to see the css file being used and check if the file has hero-unit1 class. If it does not goto the assets folder in your project and empty it. this will cause yii to recreate those assets for widgets

Comment: Hi Orlymee....thanks for pointing out....but I checked out the details using chrome developer tools....and I found that the css file does have the "hero-unit1" class. In fact, I forgot to mention above...that if I do changes in the "hero-unit" class they they do reflect....but I don't want to do that, because I may use the same "hero-unit" class at different places, with slightly different settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Skatox mentioned, it appears that the Bootstrap widgets apply some default classes.  I would stick with the code you have, and then modify your CSS to use a selector of the form (note the lack of space between the classes):

```
.hero-unit1.hero-unit{
    //css code here
}
```

Alternatively, if you have two CSS items (which is what it sounds like), e.g.:

```
.hero-unit{
    //css code here
    color: yellow;
}
.hero-unit1{
    //more css code here
    color: red;
}
```

Both of these should apply to an item that has multiple classes.  The one that is loaded last is the one that will take precedence if there are overlapping elements - i.e. in the example above, color will be red, not yellow.

Depending on which CSS file you've modified, it may load before the Bootstrap CSS, which is why I suggested the multiple class selector.

Comment: Hi ernie....thanks for the response. Out of the two situations you mentioned the latter one worked for me...but the first did not....which means that both the styles were getting applied (and in the order that they were mentioned in the style sheet). Also, now I understand what Skatox was talking about. Thanks for the help, but I am still interested in getting the first solution working as well, as it looks more clean. Request you to please share some more info on that.

Comment: For the first one, both the .hero-unit, and the multi-class selector .hero-unit1.hero-unit will be applied.  Verify the order in which the CSS is being loaded, and make sure that the combined one comes last, and you over-ride anything that you need that was set in .hero-unit

Comment: okay....so effectively the first approach also requires things to come in the specific order....then its the same as the second approach....right?...I had kept it first in order...so it didn't work for me earlier. I am slightly confused as to what is the difference between the two tags -- ".hero-unit1.hero-unit" and only ".hero-unit1"......i.e. Why I should be using approach1 or approach two.......but thanks a lot for your help and clarification !!

Comment: Ack, I was mistaken in my previous comment.  With the combined method, only the combined selector should apply, as it has a higher specificity.  My guess would be that you had a period between the two classes, or that the .hero-unit css is actually using a more specific selector.

Comment: Yes....even I was expecting that, but it did not work if I placed it before the ".hero-unit" tag. If I placed it after, then it worked, which means that order was playing a role.

Comment: Hi ernie....I have asked one more qs regarding yii-bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441966/yii-bootstrap-opening-modal-window-from-bootnavbar....would be very thankful if you can share some thoughts on that as well !

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how developers created widget's htmlOptions, on Bootstrap widgets there are some default classes because their appeareance and functionality depends on them: CSS classes, Javascript selectors, etc.

So you shouldn't remove it, if you wanna do something else then play with the combination of your class and the default one.

Comment: Hi Skatox....sorry....didn't understand your explanation. I am not trying to remove anything. I am just trying to add one more class -- "hero-unit1" so that the default behavior remains intact, while I can still do some more changes at my end.

Comment: Mmm, if you wanna add classes just do like this: 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'hero-unit1 hero-unit'). I don't believe order will affect because most widgets replaces the class attribute with your parameter. Is this what you want?

Comment: Actually....I did not want to add classes....I wanted to override default....but i think here the component always reads the default configuration...and the only way that came out of discussion with ernie is to appropriately order the styles in the css file !!

Comment: Hi skatox....I have asked one more qs regarding yii-bootstrap: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441966/yii-bootstrap-opening-modal-window-from-bootnavbar....would be very thankful if you can share some thoughts on that as well !

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit late for the OP, but Ill post here for others who might be wondering about the default classes set by Yii-Bootstrap.

Yii-Bootstrap always sets some default classes because bootstrap itself requires them. This way we can make sure that they are always applied.

Instead of removing default classes you are supposed to override them in your own stylesheets.

I hope this clears things out.